# JavaScript - clone of Template with cloneNode and Json data

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create several elements using JSON data with a template, by creating a clone of the template and appending them to the specific div.

However, when using the cloned template variable, the clone can't be used inside the function which handles the JSON data, even when this clone is above the function (which should make it global for everything the same level?).

HTML

```
<template class="content">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h3>Hello World</h3>
</template>

<div class="box">

</div>
```

JS

```
let content = document.querySelector(".content").content;
let box = document.querySelector(".box");

doStuff();

function doStuff() {
  let content = document.querySelector(".content").content;
  let box = document.querySelector(".box");
  //make a clone of the template
  let clone = content.cloneNode(true);

  // change content of H2
  clone.querySelector("h2").textContent = "First Box";

  // change content of H3 with data fetched from API
  fetch("http://kea-alt-del.dk/t5/api/product?id=21").then(e => e.json()).then(productJson => otherStuff(productJson));

  function otherStuff(productJson) {
    clone.querySelector("h3").textContent = productJson.name;

  }

  // add the clone to the box div
  box.appendChild(clone);

}
```

Working fiddle as Example: https://jsfiddle.net/c1x98hmh/4/
We can see in the result that the h2 content has been changed, however, h3 remains unchanged. Console log tells me that clone is null.

How come this example works when we change the template element to a div?
(I need this for Json, that's why I have a template, function, clone and inside function)

Comment: The fiddle works perfectly fine for me; both h2 and h3 are changed. What browser are you using? I've got firefox 56.0.3

Comment: @Cauterite , I can see that you were right, I updated my code and the fiddle with the JSON Data, which explains my issue more detailed and which is not working now. The console gives me this as error log `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clone` is a **DocumentFragment** object. [Here's what appendChild does with a DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a DocumentFragment, the entire contents of the DocumentFragment are moved into the child list of the specified parent node.

keyword being "moved" — that's why `clone` is empty when `otherStuff` is called.

Comment: @tanckom you could query `box` instead of clone; you could take a reference to h3 before calling appendChild; you could wrap all the template contents in another element and use that as your `clone` instead of the documentfragment

Comment: Unfortunately, I have an array of objects which means I can't use one productJson.name for every box, but in a forEach loop, I need to change the content of each h3 accordingly to the current productJson.name in the loop

Comment: i don't see how any of my 3 suggestions conflict with your requirements

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since the `<template>` element is not to be rendered by the browser, its content is not part of the DOM and thus it is not possible to query it with a DOM query such as `document.querySelector()`.

EDIT: It is confirmed here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

> **Content is considered not to be in the document.** Using `document.getElementById()` or `querySelector()` in the main page won't return child nodes of a template.

Comment: I know the content exists in the "cloud" and can the clone be used inside JS to change content etc. but I'm just wondering why using the clone inside another function with the same level is not working. Or what could be the alternative?